# R: Dealing with functions that sometimes crash the R session?

Tags: r, exception, crash

Have an R function ( let's call it MyFunction ) that sometimes crashes the R session , most of the time it does not.
Have to apply this function to a large number of objects in a sequential manner.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(objects))
{
     result[i] <- MyFunction(objects[i]);
}
```

I'm coming from a C# background - where functions rarely crash the "session" and programmers normally surround such function calls in  try - catch blocks. However, in R I've seen **some** functions that just crash the session and using tryCatch is of no help since the function does not cause an exception but a full blast session crash ;-)

Just wondering what's the best way of "catching" the crash.
I'm considering writing a Python script that calls the R function from Python ( via one of the R-Python connectors ) and catching the R crash in Python. Would that work ?
Any advise ?

Cheers !

Comment: Could you provide a few examples of functions that crash the session? They're very rare in my experience, and are usually (always?) due to a bug in R, an R package, or external programs linked to by the R session.

Comment: As @JoshO'Brien said, a crash is a bug. Try to reproduce the bug otherwise you will not resolve the problem. Another advise if you have some warnings try to resolve them also.

Comment: I get the idea. However, the function MyFunction comes from some co - workers , let's say that they are very possessive about it , they blame the "input" to the function as the cause of the crash (they say that it's because of the fact that input is bad / low quality ). However, apart from this function, I once did manage to set up a SQL query via sqldf package that does crash the R session full blast and I can replicate.

Comment: I should add that most software maintainers will want to know about bugs that cause their software to crash. Don't know about your co-workers, but the **sqldf** maintainers would probably appreciate a bug report that includes a reproducible example that crashes the session. Reporting things like that is one way that users of OSS give can back to the community.

Comment: Write a temporary wrapper around `MyFunction` that saves the inputs into a file before calling the function. After it crashes, start a new session and load those "bad" inputs. When you can identify what your co-workers mean by "bad/low quality" (it could be numeric data where integers are expected, collinearity in your data, etc.), start writing a high-level wrapper that checks for these conditions and either cleans the data or errors out gracefully via `stop`. This is how I've dealt with at least two R packages crashing on too many occasions: `glpkAPI` and `geometry`.

Comment: This is a "political" situation too ... can't change the function even if I found out why it crashes :-)

Comment: You wouldn't be changing their function. You'd be calling it from within a function of your own (a "wrapper"), which makes sure that the inputs meet all the "good data" assumptions before the buggy function is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `mcparallel` function from the parallel package to run the function in a forked process. That way, if it crashes R, only the subprocess crashes, and an error is returned to the main process. If you want to apply this function to a large number of objects and collect the results in a list, use `mclapply`

Answer (score 0):

Hello such behaviour is very rare in my experience. You might not know that there is a debuger that can help you to go step by step in you function.

```
install.packages('debug') #install the debug package
library(debug)
mtrace(myFunctionToBeDebuged) #this function will start the debuger
mtrace(myFunctionToBeDebuged, FALSE) #to stop the function to be traced
```

NOTE: when you are in the debuger, should you want to quit it do `qqq()`

Comment: The debugger function seems not to work for functions that employ the apply family. Would you hapen to know what could be used instead, thank you